How to capture input of deltacast capture card using ffmpeg or any tool?Please help me?
How to capture input of deltacast capture card using ffmpeg or any tool?Please help me?
iam installed the driver for deltacast elp hd 80 card.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

In linux ubuntu , i want to capture in command line without gui or applications. any tool or script to capture video ,because we stream using ffmpeg or any tool.

Use OBS and create a scene, then create a source and select your capture card
OBS is very useful if you want to record or stream your captures
https://obsproject.com/
Step 1

Step 2

Step 3

Step 4

Then you click okay and your capture card should show up on screen, the rest is pretty simple to figure out.
In step 4 you configure what OBS will pickup from the capture card, it should pick up audio from the card. If you want to add a microphone to the capture so you can talk while you record or stream you go through this process again and select "Audio Input Capture" rather than "Video Capture Device"
OBS has twitch integration, if you go into settings and go to "stream" option, you can login and live stream to twitch and various other websites.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I think a missing part of OP's question is what outputs this does? If the capture card in question acts like a webcam, its trivial. If its something non standard, it gets trickier

In linux ubuntu , i want to capture in command line without gui or applications. any tool or script to capture video ,because we stream using ffmpeg or any tool.

In linux ubuntu , i want to capture in command line without gui or applications. any tool or script to capture video ,because we stream using ffmpeg or any tool.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
